# How to recursively change filenames for upper to lower case through bat file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, recursion

I have been expanding on the issue solved here: https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase/412413#412413

I wish to change filenames from upper case to lower case and since files are stored in mulitple folders I wish to do it recursively.

I have tried the following:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "somefolder"
FOR /D %%G in (*) DO (
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR %%G /l/b/a-d') DO (RENAME "%%f"  "%%f"))
```

I get "the system cannot find the path specified errors".
I am sure I am overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives the path error because RENAME cannot find the file. The DIR command lists files in a subdirectory, but your current directory is not the subdirectory.

You have other problems - you are not doing a recursive folder search. The /D option only lists immediate child folders. Your code would miss files in the root "somefolder", as well as any folders that are two or more levels deep.

Also, the original code from SuperUser is flawed. The use of `"tokens=*"` will strip leading spaces. It is possible (however unlikely) for a file name to begin with a space, and then the code would break. One correct syntax to use is `for /f "eol=: delims=" ...`.

The [MichaelS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502210/1012053) using the `dir /s` option cannot work because the REN command does not accept path information in the target - only the file name and extension can be used. Normally you would solve that problem by using `%%~nxF`, but that reverts to the original case of the file name!

Here is a proper recursive solution for use on the command line:

```
for /r "somePath" %D in (.) do @for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /l/b/a-d "%D"') do @ren "%D\%F" "%F"
```

And from a batch script

```
@echo off
for /r "somePath" %%D in (.) do for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /l/b/a-d "%%D"') do ren "%%D\%%F" "%%F"
```

If you are willing to go beyond native cmd.exe commands, then another option is my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) that supports options to convert names to upper or lower case. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe files needed. Full documentation is built in - accessed from the command line via `jren /?`, or `jren /??` if you want paged output.

With JREN, the recursive solution is as simple as:

```
jren "^" "" /s /l
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over the subdirectories. Simply add `/s` to the dir command:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /l/b/a-d/s') DO (RENAME "%%f"  "%%f")
```

`/s` will include all subfolders recursively.

Comment: Unfortunatley this does not work. What do you mean by "don't neet to loop over the subdirectories"? I should skip the line starting with FOR /D?

Comment: I think the line should look like this: `for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /S /B /L /A:-D "%%~G"') do rename "%%~F"  "%%~nxF")`

Comment: Just skip the first FOR-loop. The line of code I've posted should be enough. You can also skip `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` as you aren't using delayed expansion, at least not in this part of your code.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed an error in my code. I've modified it so now it should work. %%G was wrong.

Comment: @MichaelS.  Your code FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /l/b/a-d/s') DO (RENAME "%%f"  "%%f") results in "The syntax of the command is incorrect". This seems to be due to the /s.

Comment: This strategy cannot work. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38514435/1012053)